# How to set the date as a placeholder when view loads?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

*I am using this [plugin](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/) with Angular which is actually this [extension](https://github.com/diosney/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker-directive) 
When the view loads all you see is an empty input, when you click on that input, the calendar comes up and today's date is displayed in that input.*

**What I need is to load today's date in the input when the view is ready.**

Here the way I am using it

```
<input type='text' datetimepicker
       datetimepicker-options="{format: 'MM/DD/YYYY', useCurrent: true}"/>
```

**what do you recommend ?**

**EDIT**

*I added `autofocus` to the input, and the datepicker it's been displayed, not only the date which is what I need.*

MY CONTROLLER:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('palpatine')
    .controller('RotationsCtrl', RotationsCtrl);

  /* @ngInject */
  function RotationsCtrl (Rotations, $scope, $rootScope, $state) {
    /*jshint validthis: true */
    var vm = this;

    activate();

    function activate () {

      $(document).ready(function () {

        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        if(dd<10) {
            dd='0'+dd
        }

        if(mm<10) {
            mm='0'+mm
        }

        today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;

        $scope.today = moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY");

        console.log(today);

        $scope.datetimepickerOptions = {
          format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
          defaultDate: today
        };


      });

    }
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `defaultDate` to current date. This will override `useCurrent`, so it's not needed anymore.

**In controller**

```
$scope.datetimepickerOptions = {
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY', 
    defaultDate: new Date()
};
```

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' 
       datetimepicker
       datetimepicker-options="{{datetimepickerOptions}}"/>
```

**EDIT**

It turned out that [diosney/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker-directive](https://github.com/diosney/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker-directive) had a bug with `defaultDate` in 0.1.3 release. Solution was to update it to master branch.

**bower.json**

```
"angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker-directive": "#master"
```

and run

```
bower update
```

Comment: got this error: `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Date' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 41 of the expression [{format: 'MM/DD/YYYY', defaultDate: new Date()}] starting at [Date()}].`

Comment: I did it this way but still not working. Everytime the view loads, the input is empty.

Comment: You have to use master branch version of diosney/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker-directive since older version have bug wth `defaultDate`. See [issue for defaultDate](https://github.com/diosney/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker-directive/issues/9).

Comment: but how do I use that branch? I mean, all I did was download the project he has on Git

Comment: Did you download it under releases or just downloaded current version? If current, then it is master.

Comment: I have this `"angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker-directive": "~0.1.3",` on my bower.json, which seems to be the last release

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100080/discussion-between-rene-korss-and-theunnamed).

Answer (score 0):

Give focus to the text input then blur it...

```
 angular.element('.your_input_class_name').trigger('focus');
 angular.element('.your_input_class_name').trigger('blur');
```

or

```
 document.getElementById('your_input_id').focus();
 document.getElementById('your_input_id').blur();
```

Comment: If you blur it automatically date picker will go out

Comment: For angular this could be a solution ,otherwise the current date have to capture in a controller using javascript and paste as a value in the input field

Comment: @krishnakumarsekar show me this second way you just said

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code?

[ref](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#enableddisabled-dates)

```
<input type='text' 
       datetimepicker
       datetimepicker-options="{format: 'MM/DD/YYYY', defaultDate: '01/01/2016'}"/>
```

**Edit**

On seeing the updated question i could notice that datetimepicker module is not loaded in the module. Inject the module as given below

```
angular
  .module('palpatine', [
    // Other injected modules.

    'datetimepicker'
  ]);
```

Comment: that is what I am doing, but the date is always the same, I need it to be today's date

Comment: @TheUnnamed In that case Rene Kross solution should work, otherwise can you create a jsfiddle/plunkr and let us know the link ?

Comment: with that solution I did console.log and got this `Object {format: "MM/DD/YYYY", defaultDate: Thu Jan 07 2016 12:00:20 GMT-0600 (CST)}`, why I am not getting the same in the input ? could be because of the date format ?

Comment: @TheUnnamed Can you post you full code controller, view, module etc?

Comment: @TheUnnamed Hi Check my updated answer i think you have missed to load the datetimepicker app in your module

Comment: actually I have that module in the main app.js, so I guess I don't need to call it anymore in the other files

Answer (score 0):

If u are just looking for a placeholder as current date. Add placeholder attribute on input and use today as value.